# Get array of dates seperated by weeks for a given month and year in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I am collecting the month and the year from a form and want to generate an array of the number of dates on that particular month seperated by weeks assuming `sunday` as the beginning of week.

For example, if the input is `month=January` and `year=2018`, the desired result is

```
$array_of_dates =Array ( [Week 1] => '01/01/2018',.....,'06/01/2018'
                         [Week 2] => '07/01/2018',.....,'13/01/2018' 
                         [Week 3] => '14/01/2018',.....,'20/01/2018'
                         [Week 4] => '21/01/2018',.....,'27/01/2018' 
                         [Week 5] => '28/01/2018',.....,'31/01/2018' )
```

I tried this

```
function weeks_in_month($month, $year) {
   $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
   $end = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('t', $start), $year);
   $start_week = date('W', $start);
   $end_week = date('W', $end);

if ($end_week < $start_week) { // Month wraps
  return ((52 + $end_week) - $start_week) + 1;
}

return ($end_week - $start_week) + 1;
}
```

But this only gives me the number of weeks for that month.

Comment: I found this topics, may be it helps you.
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861384/php-get-start-and-end-date-of-a-week-by-weeknumber)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for convenience methods such as `add` to increment days, and `format` to get the total number of days in a month as well as the respective day of the week.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/IKGMG

```
function weeks_in_month($month, $year)
{
    $dates = [];

    $week = 1;
    $date = new DateTime("$year-$month-01");
    $days = (int)$date->format('t'); // total number of days in the month

    $oneDay = new DateInterval('P1D');

    for ($day = 1; $day <= $days; $day++) {
        $dates["Week $week"] []= $date->format('d/m/Y');

        $dayOfWeek = $date->format('l');
        if ($dayOfWeek === 'Saturday') {
            $week++;
        }

        $date->add($oneDay);
    }

    return $dates;
}

print_r(weeks_in_month(1, 2018));
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [Week 1] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 01/01/2018
>             [1] => 02/01/2018
>             [2] => 03/01/2018
>             [3] => 04/01/2018
>             [4] => 05/01/2018
>             [5] => 06/01/2018
>         )
>
>     [Week 2] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 07/01/2018
>             [1] => 08/01/2018
>             [2] => 09/01/2018
>             [3] => 10/01/2018
>             [4] => 11/01/2018
>             [5] => 12/01/2018
>             [6] => 13/01/2018
>         )
>
>     [Week 3] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 14/01/2018
>             [1] => 15/01/2018
>             [2] => 16/01/2018
>             [3] => 17/01/2018
>             [4] => 18/01/2018
>             [5] => 19/01/2018
>             [6] => 20/01/2018
>         )
>
>     [Week 4] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 21/01/2018
>             [1] => 22/01/2018
>             [2] => 23/01/2018
>             [3] => 24/01/2018
>             [4] => 25/01/2018
>             [5] => 26/01/2018
>             [6] => 27/01/2018
>         )
>
>     [Week 5] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 28/01/2018
>             [1] => 29/01/2018
>             [2] => 30/01/2018
>             [3] => 31/01/2018
>         )
>
> )
> ```