# How to get the day based on week number in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So i have a json object which displays year, month and week of year:

```
{
  "year": 2021,
  "month": 8,
  "week": 31,
},
{
  "year": 2021,
  "month": 8,
  "week": 32,
}
```

My question is how can i iterate through the json object then convert the week of year into day of month where the day is the end of the week and then pass in the year, month and day of month into a DateTime object in flutter like this:

```
DateTime(2021,8,7)
DateTime(2021,8,14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the week with a 7 to get the total number of days. Like

```
 int totaldays = week*7;
 final extraDuration = Duration(days: totaldays);
 final startDate = DateTime(2021);

  final newDateTime = startDate.add(extraDuration);

 print(newDateTime);
 print(newDateTime.next(DateTime.friday));
```

Comment: Thank you this is the answer i was looking for

Comment: This won't necessarily return a day "at the end of the week", whatever the OP means by that.

Comment: That is true. I just showed a fraction of the json data i am using it is actually all weeks from the year 2021. When i used the example i noticed that after i use week 35 i get 3 september which is not the the end of the first week of that month

Comment: I found the solution but it is in php. I am not sure how i can achieve the same with dart: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861384/php-get-start-and-end-date-of-a-week-by-weeknumber

Comment: Just use `print(someDay.next(DateTime.friday))` Edited my answer too.